# Blender motion blur too long

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, motion-blur

I don't like how long the trail of this motion blur is. I know the curves can be manipulated, but I'm thinking I need something that just changes how long the blur lasts.

Question 1: Is this a situation where I should adjust the shutter, and if so, what would be the best value? Animation is set for 24fps.

Question 2: Should I avoid motion blur entirely, and what is the most appropriate setting for a slow motion glass shattering scene?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit:** After lowering my shutter to the correct setting (thank you @cegaton), another issue occurred, as mentioned in comments.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a smaller shutter value.

[image]

A smaller number would give you less blur, freezing the action. Same effect as a faster shutter speed on a real camera, where the film or sensor is exposed less time to the light.

A larger value would result in more blur, the same way as using a longer exposure time on a real camera.

If you are curious of where the default value of 0.5 comes from, you can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_disc_shutter. Motion picture cameras have a rotating shutter in the form of a semi-circle, half the time the film is held in place while is being exposed to the light, the other half of the time the shutter is closed while the film transport mechanism moves the film for the next frame to be exposed.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I would like to add that sometimes when I render, even with the shutter at .01, I get a never-ending trail of blur, which is likely due to a cache issue.

Comment: @BlueHelmet For very fast blur you can use smaller values than 0.01 if you type them directly instead of just srcolling.

Comment: Edit above, for reference, and in case anyone else experiences the anomaly. It looks fine on one render, but then deviates on another, after a crash.

Comment: Instead of adding different topics to the original question, please ask another question about this new issue

Comment: Thanks, not meant as another question. Just for reference. I'm pretty sure it's a cache issue.

Comment: It is a valid question maybe someone knows the answer, and it might help others who run into a similar issue.